# How do I iterate over a list of links onto multiple files with a specific range on each file?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm trying to iterate through a list of links and I would like it to be divided up into several files in order.
This is what the outline would look like.

The **root** file (1st file) would contain links ranging from 1-101.

Then the **second level** of files (files 2-10) would contain links ranging from 101-1101 (10 links per file).

Ex. `102-111 are links on file 2, 112-121 are links on file 3, 122-131 are links on file 4, etc.`

How do I make it so that I can loop through 10 links per file on the **second level** with the correct index position?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are looking for.  Do you have a big list that you want to write to files?

Answer (score 0):

Get list of all files and iterate through it

```
import os 
listOfFiles = os.listdir("./") # "./" path to folader with files
for file in listOfFiles:
# do what y want with file
```